# Magento invalid product urls

Tags: url, development, core

I've been trying to get correct product urls for orders. By that I mean that when an order is created, i want to get the product url which will correspond to the store in which the order was made. 
At first I've been using the `getProductUrl()` but this method sometime returned to me urls with admin path. 
My second try was using the following code:

```
Mage::app()->getStore($order->getStoreId())->getUrl($product->getUrlKey());
```

However, sometimes I get invalid urls.

What is the correct way to get a valid product url for each order, which will correspond to the correct store?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this code :

```
echo $this->getBaseUrl().$product->getUrlKey().".html";
```

OR this :

```
echo $this->getBaseUrl().$product->getUrlPath();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code snippet

```
echo Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_item->getProductId())->getProductUrl()
```